# I'm creating react app, on "npm start" i'm getting this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

[image]

npm start is not working, giving this error, also it was showing vulnerabilities- 82 moderate, 4 high.

Answer (score 0):

update your npm package but if that did not fix then try to do 'npm audit fix' hope this helps

Comment: i updated nodejs, its working now. thanks